# Angular 13 Bootstrap 5 - How add dynamic datalist options

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5

Angular 13
Bootstrap 5

datalist.component.html

```
<div>
  <label for="{{ id }}" class="form-label">{{ label }}</label>
  <input
    class="form-control"
    list="{{ datalistOptions }}"
    [id]="id"
    [placeholder]="placeholder"
  />
  <datalist [id]="datalistOptions">
    <option
      *ngFor="let option of datalistOptions"
      value="{{ option }}"
    ></option>
  </datalist>
</div>
```

datalist.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datalist',
  templateUrl: './datalist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datalist.component.css']
})
export class DatalistComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() id: string = '';
  @Input() label: string = '';
  @Input() placeholder: string = '';
  @Input() datalistId: string = '';
  @Input() datalistOptions: string[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<form>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Dynamic Dataset</legend>
  <app-datalist
        id="autocomplete"
        label="autocomplete label"
        placeholder="autocomplete placeholder"
        datalistId="dataoptions"
        [datalistOptions]="datalistOptions"
      ></app-datalist>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  datalistOptions = [
    'Bootstrap',
    'Foundation',
    'Semantic UI',
    'Bulma',
    'Materialize',
  ];
}
```

Error is "Can't bind to 'list' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. But the error isn't there when I have static options instead of dynamic options. Here is the Stackblitz, with the static options commented out and the dynamic options shown with error:

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ahvyyn?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: shouldnt it be [list]="datalistOptions"?

Comment: It doesn't matter either way works. Or, doesn't work, in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

use the [attr.list]="" syntax instead of [list].

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12759